# Pandas mean of rows following a matching condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

Lets say I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": [100,200,300,400,100,200,300,np.nan],
                   "correct": [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

Printed:

```
   correct   time
0        1  100.0
1        1  200.0
2        0  300.0
3        1  400.0
4        1  100.0
5        0  200.0
6        0  300.0
7        0    NaN
```

I want to calculate the mean of `time` for only the rows **following** rows where `correct` is equal to `0`. So in the above dataframe I want to calculate the mean of `400`, `300`, and `NaN` (which will give `350`)

I need to be careful of handling `NaN` values, and literal edge cases where the last row has `correct == 0` but there isn't a row following it

Whats the most efficient way to do this in Pandas without having to resort to looping through the dataframe (my current implementation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [shift()](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) method:

```
In [55]: df.loc[df.correct.shift() == 0, 'time'].mean()
Out[55]: 350.0
```

Explanation:

```
In [53]: df.correct.shift()
Out[53]:
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
Name: correct, dtype: float64

In [54]: df.loc[df.correct.shift() == 0, 'time']
Out[54]:
3    400.0
6    300.0
7      NaN
Name: time, dtype: float64
```